# Embed Facebook fan page into view in Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-page

My Android app consists of a simple tablayout (3 tabs).

Let's say the user chooses tab #2. Now I would like to show the user a specific fan page, just the recent posts/updates. If it can be embedded directly into the view below the tab, that'd be best (no popup/dialog).
I know that if the user should have the opportunity to 'like'/comment on anything, the app needs to be authorized. I have been able to get through that by using the guides on the Facebook API site.

But I just don't know how to show the user the fan page itself. Possible?

Side question: what if a user does not have a Facebook account? Will he/she be unable to view the fan page then?

Comment: i know that a lot of fan pages don't need a login when viewing them from a computer browser so it should be the same for the webview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one could answer, I ended up removing this feature from my app.

Comment: I wish I could do the same xD