# How to show specific facebook page in my app?

Tags: android, facebook

How do I embed a Facebook page in Android, without having to use a `webView`?
I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946427/embed-facebook-fan-page-into-view-in-android-app), but this question has no answers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get posts from a specific page in your app, all you have to do is issue a `GET` on `PAGE_ID/feed`.  For example, to see the posts my Page, InstaWifi, has made, you can click on this link here to see what the response would look like:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=325806087495884%2Ffeed

Once you receive this JSON, you can parse it to display the content in your app.

Comment: Thank you that could help
but if i want to use it in my app i have to use the facebook SDK right ?
another question can i do this without entering access token ? because i don't want to force the user to login to use the app

Comment: Yes, you have to use the Facebook SDK, and yes you have to have an access token to access this information.  Unfortunately there is no other way, does that answer your question?

Comment: Not really because i don't want to force the user to login an app like what i am talking about, it's for news page on faceook, and you don't have to login or anything

http://www.mediafire.com/?icp81ad25c1nw77

Comment: Well that's too bad.  The answer remains the same regardless, you need a valid access token in order to get the posts from a FB Page and to get one you have to use the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Thank you Jesse if there is no other answer in tow days i will accept yours

Comment: Is my question stupid ?? why people voting down ?

Comment: @AlaaL did you figure out now? how can i achive this?

Comment: I've just saw an app that fetch from Facebook without login, so it is possible. after digging around you should use the graph api of Facebook SDK. i hope someone will post a better answer than me, Right now i'm trying to do it myself, since i'm stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Don't forget to add permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
but the user still can enter another url and facebook adds, notifications, and are showed in the page
I only want to get the posts from the page and show it in my app